# install Elasticsearch metricbeat in FreeBSD

Tags: elasticsearch, freebsd

I am unable to find a proper way to install metricbeat on FreeBSD [8.X/9.X/10.1]. It is neither available in Ports nor a cleaner approach to compile it from source is available.

Could you please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

metricbeat is availabe in freebsd ports https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/sysutils/metricbeat/?pathrev=434495

For reference https://www.freshports.org/sysutils/metricbeat. 
Make sure the dependencies are met in your environment.

you can checkout the ports using the command: svn checkout https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head /usr/ports

once you have the port in your /usr/ports/sysutils/metricbeat, a simple make should get you there.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
pkg install beats
```

From the **Notes from UPDATING** [/usr/ports/UPDATING](https://www.freshports.org/sysutils/metricbeat)

> The three elasticsearch beats ports have merged into one single port
>         systuils/beats

```
2017-02-20
Affects: sysutils/filebeat sysutils/metricbeat sysutils/packetbeat
Author: girgen@FreeBSD.org
Reason: 
  The three elasticsearch beats ports have merged into one single port
  systuils/beats that installs all of the above and some more. The reason is to
  make the port more maintainable and also that the new heartbeat beat would
  conflict with sysutils/heartbeat.
```

This is part of  the output from `pkg info beats`:

```
beats-6.2.4_1
Name           : beats
Version        : 6.2.4_1
Installed on   : Thu Jun 14 21:46:54 2018 UTC
Origin         : sysutils/beats
Architecture   : FreeBSD:11:amd64
Prefix         : /usr/local
Categories     : sysutils
Licenses       : APACHE20
Maintainer     : elastic@FreeBSD.org
WWW            : https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/
Comment        : Collect logs locally and send to remote logstash
Options        :
        FILEBEAT       : on
        HEARTBEAT      : on
        METRICBEAT     : on
        PACKETBEAT     : on
...
```

If the package you need is not available, you could update the file `/etc/pkg/FreeBSD.conf` to use the `latest` available ports by using something like:

```
FreeBSD: {
  url: "pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/${ABI}/latest",
  mirror_type: "srv",
  signature_type: "fingerprints",
  fingerprints: "/usr/share/keys/pkg",
  enabled: yes
}
```

Notice the use of `latest` in the URL instead of `quarterly`

Comment: Hi, The problem is, it's not available. If it would have been available, I would have ran the command pkg install beats. The first solution works and we can close this thread

Comment: @KarthiKeyan here you have it for 10: http://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:10:amd64/latest/All/beats-6.2.4_1.txz, check updated answer for using `latest` in the pkg repos

Comment: hi @nbari, Thanks. I downloaded the tar and could see problems. 1. unxz beats-6.2.4_1.tx 2) tar -xvf beats-6.2.4_1.tar 3) ls
+COMPACT_MANIFEST beats-6.2.4_1.tar var
+MANIFEST  usr